# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl | jetty:run

Tags: maven-3, maven-jetty-plugin

I am getting

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl
```

while using jetty:run plugin on a web project.

The issue is occurring only on some machines while working on some !

Java Version Used : 7
Maven Version : 3.1

Relevant dependencies and plugins:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was not able to codify the XMLs. Hence the screenshots...

Answer (score 15):

Adding this dependency fixed it :-

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: For my case the problem was that the jetty port was already bound (i had another server at that port running). Looking at the console message more closely before the noClassFound Exception I noticed this "goal org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (default-cli) on project xxx: Failure: Address already in use: JVM_Bind"

Answer (score 3):

If you are running jetty on a port below 1024 on linux or osx this could be caused by the process not having permissions to bind to the port. In my case above the stack trace was the error.

> Blockquote[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.4.v20120524:run (default-cli) on project projectName: Failure: Permission denied -> [Help 1]
>   Blockquote

Running the command with sudo fixed the issue.

Comment: this fixed my issue.
so I use: sudo su
then: mvn jetty:run

Answer (score 0):

This is occurred for me because the port to be used  by the Jasper is already occupied by other process. I did stopped the application running on that port and restarted the app it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this configuration in **pom.xml** in **ide**->**idea**

```
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- resource plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- compiler plugin, set JDK version -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <verbose />
                    <bootclasspath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- deploye plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- war plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <!-- jetty plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.26</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>tomcat.port</name>
                        <value>8098</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
                <webApp>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}.war</webApp>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>8088</port>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```